# DockPanel Suite tab sorting

Tags: .net, dockpanel-suite

one of my projects uses WeiFen Luo's DockPanel Suite http://dockpanelsuite.com/. Now customer demands to have tabs sorted in a given order when in Document view.

The tabs are all instances of the same DockContent-derived class. It carries a float by which to sort.

DockPanel.Contents is a DockContentCollection that sadly doesn't provide a Sort method like other collections. It's also not possible to delete DockContents from it in order to add them in the correct order.

But user can drag a tab and drop it onto another to change their order.

Does anyone know how to do that "insert tab1 in tab2's place" programatically?

I know I should ask in a library-dependent forum, the "how to ask a question" entry there leads here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you dig into the sample project's `MainForm.menuItemLayoutByCode_Click` method, you can see how to control layout via C# code.

```
doc1.Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document);
doc2.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc3.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc4.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
```

The effect of above code is that Document4 shows as the active tab, while the previous three are in order.

So to move Document1 and Document2, you can use

```
doc1.Show(dockPanel, DockState.Document);
doc2.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc3.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc4.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc1.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
doc2.Show(doc1.Pane, null);
```

Do you get it? It is simply a stack, and you can fully control the order.

Comment: I see. I got a little confused about the usage of Panel vs Pane. But with the Pane instance I got it to work the way it should:

`dockContentInstance.Show(panelInstance.ActiveDocumentPane, neighbouringDockContentInstance);`

to sort a DockContent instance next to another one.