# Get DockPanel suite tab order

Tags: c#, dockpanel-suite

Is there some collection or some other property, where it is possible to get the current order of tabs in the DockPanel Suite? I open several tabs in some order by default and then, after some action, I want to get the current tabs order. The user can change tabs order manually. There is a `DockPanel.Contents` collection, but the order in this collection is not corresponding with the real tabs order. I was also not able to find some index property, or something like that in the `DockContent`.
There is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28021246/1108200) question which tells me, how to show tabs in the specified order, but there is no information about also getting the order.

Comment: No built-in support. You'd better track the tabs in your own app.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I track the tabs order, when they are manually reordered?